# Why is my js.d3 code not displaying axis?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have tried to make a set of x and y axis with this code and I'm stumped as to why they are not showing up. I want it to display a set of axis with ranges of -10 to 10, and the red line to sit above these axes. I am not sure why specifically the axis aren't working at this stage, the latter portion of my code has the axis code in it.

```
//variable declaration
var width = 500;
var height = 300;
var margin = 10;
//svg setup
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append('g') 
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")" )
//line setup
svg.append('line')
   .attr({
  x1: 0,
  y1: 0,
  x2: 250,
  y2: 250
});
//scales and axis setup
var scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([-10, 10])
        .domain([0, width])


var scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([-10, 10])
        .domain([height, 0])

var axisX = d3.svg.axis()
               .scale(scaleX)  
               .orient("bottom");

var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
               .scale(scaleY)
               .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + "," + height/2 + ")")
   .call(axisX);

svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + "0)") 
   .call(axisY);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some mistakes,like mapping goes from domain to range not range to domain and use of Svg instead of svg and svg.scale instead of d3.scale etc

see for yourself 
https://jsfiddle.net/dango_x_daikazoku/33g9pLqe/4/

```
var width = 500;
var height = 300;
var margin = 30;

//svg setup
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

//line setup


//scales and axis setup
var scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([-10, 10])
  .range([0, width])

var scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([-10, 10])
  .range([height, 0])

var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(scaleY)
  .orient("left");

var axisX = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(scaleX)
  .orient("bottom");

svg.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'y-axis axis')
  .call(axisY);

svg.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'x-axis axis')
  .call(axisX)
  .attr('transform', 'translate( 0, 250)')
```